# What is the effect of {} in \eqalign?

Tags: math-mode, tex-core, plain-tex

```
$$\eqalign{&{}+7=b\cr}$$
```

and

```
$$\eqalign{&+7=b\cr}$$
```

are the same; but

```
$$\eqalign{{}+7=b\cr}$$
```

and

```
$$\eqalign{+7=b\cr}$$
```

differ from each other (the first has more space between `+` and `7`). In all cases "`+`" is shown as `\mathbin` in `\showlists`. Why spacing is different with and without `{}` when `&` is used and when it is not?

*NOTE: In the `\displaylines` example on p.196 of TeXbook it is mentioned that `{}` serves to make `+` a binary operation. This may be true for `\displaylines`, but it is not true for `\eqalign`, as demonstrated above.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\tracingonline1
\showboxdepth\maxdimen

1
$$\eqalign{{}+7=b\cr}\showlists$$


2
$$\eqalign{+7=b\cr}\showlists$$

\bye
```

a `{}` just makes an empty `\mathord`, and the`\mathbin` from `+` gets treated like a `\mathord` unless it is not at the start or end of a list.

In the first case you see

```
.....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
.....\glue(\medmuskip) 2.22217 plus 1.11108 minus 2.22217
.....\tenrm +
.....\glue(\medmuskip) 2.22217 plus 1.11108 minus 2.22217
.....\tenrm 7
```

that is an empty mathord atom, medmuskip either side of the + as it is a mathbin, then 7

In the second case you see

```
.....\tenrm +
.....\tenrm 7
```

no leading empty mathord (shown as `\hbox`) then + and 7 with no spacing as the `\mathbin` nature of `+` is suppressed.

Your first example, after the `&` the `{}` has no effect as the `\eqalign` macro adds a `{}` in the second column already:

```
\def\eqalign#1{\null\,\vcenter{\openup\jot\m@th
  \ialign{\strut\hfil$\displaystyle{##}$&$\displaystyle{{}##}$\hfil
      \crcr#1\crcr}}\,}
```

so the template for the second column is `{}##` and already starts with an empty mathord, so there you are comparing `{}+7` and `{}{}+7` which are the same output.